# Loop Subtract value from one workbook in separate workbook

Tags: vba, loops, excel

The idea is this...
If the value in column A (workbook "source") is equal to the value in column Q (workbook "affected") then the values in the corresponding column F (workbook "source") is subtracted from column T (workbook "affected"). But it isn't working. I'm not receiving any error of any kind, it just doesn't do what I want. I appreciate any help.

```
Sub Subtract_Between_workbooks()
Dim Source As Workbook
Dim Affected As Workbook

Dim Dados As Worksheet
Dim Source_Sheet As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim N As Long
Dim M As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long

Source = Workbooks.Open("\\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\LCA_LCI Macro Writing\ResgatesEmissões.xlsb")
Affected = Workbooks.Open("\\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\LCA_LCI Macro Writing\New - Macro Writing - Controle de Lastro LCA.xlsm")

Set Dados = Workbooks(Affected).Sheets("Dados")
Set Source_Sheet = Workbooks(Source).Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = Source_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
N = Dados.Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
M = Source_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Z = 1 To LastRow
If Source_Sheet.Range("B" & i) = "LCA" And Source_Sheet.Range("D" & i) = "Resgate Final Passivo Cliente" And Source_Sheet.Range("H" & i) = "9007230" Then
    For i = 1 To M
        v1 = Source_Sheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
        v2 = Source_Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value
        For j = 1 To N
            If v1 = Dados.Cells(j, "Q").Value Then
            Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value = Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value - v2
            Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
Else: End If
Next Z

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `source` and `affected` as workbooks in your code. You need to use the `Set` keyword to make an assignment statement for objects for example:

```
Set Source = Workbooks.Open("\\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\LCA_LCI Macro Writing\ResgatesEmissões.xlsb")
```

It is always good to use the debugger if your code is not behaving like expected, and check the code line by line.

Comment: Hi Jeanno, thanks for your response. I changed those lines of code and did a debug. But it still isn't working. When I hit the Set Source line of code it reopens the excel doc and then doesn't do anything. So could it be because of this code? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you add Set for BOTH source and affected?

Answer (score 1):

On top of @Jeanno answer please check your first for loop variable.

```
For Z = 1 To LastRow
If Source_Sheet.Range("B" & i) = "LCA" And Source_Sheet.Range("D" & i) = "Resgate Final Passivo Cliente" And Source_Sheet.Range("H" & i) = "9007230" Then
```

You may need to replace i with z? since i is not defined at that moment.

Comment: good catch, he still needs to use the Set keyword for the assignment statement. Something is wrong with his debugger settings, it is not breaking on errors

Comment: you are right. I forgot to mention on top of your answer he also needs to check out for loops. Too many nested for loops can be confusing. I mean at least for me :)

Comment: Did not even realize that I did that. Have Set keyword on both. Still not working. It's as if once it hits    Set Source = Workbooks.Open("\\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\LCA_LCI Macro Writing\ResgatesEmissões.xlsb")  that it stops the code. This workbook is the workbook that has the macro. Is that the problem? Should I remove this?

Comment: If that is the case just Set source = ThisWorkbook

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to let y'all know that I got it to work. I pasted the code below. I wouldn't have figured it out without the troubleshooting help. I appreciate it a lot!

Sub Subtract_Between_workbooks()
'===Para menos Resgate===Waiting on Stack overflow
    Dim Source As Workbook
    Dim Affected As Workbook

```
Dim Dados As Worksheet
Dim Source_Sheet As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim N As Long
Dim M As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long

Set Source = Workbooks("ResgatesEmissões.xlsb")
Set Affected = Workbooks.Open("\\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\LCA_LCI Macro Writing\New - Macro Writing - Controle de Lastro LCA.xlsm")

Set Dados = Affected.Sheets("Dados")
Set Source_Sheet = Source.Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = Source_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
N = Dados.Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
M = Source_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Z = 1 To LastRow
If Source_Sheet.Range("B" & Z) = "LCA" And Source_Sheet.Range("D" & Z) = "Resgate Final Passivo Cliente" And Source_Sheet.Range("H" & Z) = "9007230" Then
    For i = 1 To M
        v1 = Source_Sheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
        v2 = Source_Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value
        For j = 1 To N
            If v1 = Dados.Cells(j, "Q").Value Then
            Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value = Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value - v2
            Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
Else: End If
Next Z
```

End Sub